# Passing a list as an argument to a function in python

Tags: python, function, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, parameter-passing

I'm new to Python and I'm struggling with passing a list as an argument to a function.

I've written a block of code to take a url, extract all links from the page and put them into a list (`links=[]`). I want to pass this list to a function that filters out any link that is not from the same domain as the starting link (aka the first in the list) and output a new list (`filtered_list = []`).
This is what I have:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start_url = "http://www.enzymebiosystems.org/"
r = requests.get(start_url)
html_content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, features='lxml')
links = []
for tag in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    links.append(tag['href'])


def filter_links(links):
    filtered_links = []
    for link in links:
        if link.startswith(links[0]):
            filtered_links.append(link)


print(filter_links(links))
```

When I run this, I get an *unfiltered* list and below that, I get None.

Eventually I want to pass the filtered list to a function that grabs the html from each page in the domain linked on the homepage, but I am trying to tackle this problem 1 process at a time. Any tips would be much appreciated, thank you :)

**EDIT**
I now can pass the list of urls to the `filter_links()` function however, I'm filtering out too much now. eventually I want to pass several different start urls through this program, so I need a generic way of filtering urls that are within the same domain as the starting url. I have used the built-in `startswith` function, but its filtering out everything except the starting url. I think I could use regex but this should work too?

Comment: You didn't *return* `filtered_links` from the function.

Comment: thank you- that did the trick! I only got the first link (the homepage) back though. I suspect its due to my `if link.startswith(links[0]):
            filtered_links.append(link)` filter.